# Is it possible to add one column everyday on a same table?

Tags: mysql

I have one table, that will have daily update for both its row and its column. The update for the row describes the new record added. The update for the column describes the daily status of the record. for example:
i have these column:`name`, `description`, `2012-11-10`,`2012-11-11`,`2012-11-12`,`2012-11-13`.

The column `2012-11-10`,`2012-11-11`,`2012-11-12`,`2012-11-13` shows the daily status, and it will always increase everyday, showing that day's status. And also the row will also increase, as there will be new records everyday. Is that possible in mysql? or there is another suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: yes, it is possible ***but (my god!) don't do it***. does it mean that if you have 1 year, your table will have 365 and 1/4 columns? :D

Comment: God Lord, what on earth you are doing and how long do you think your database table can live? ;) Have those dates recorded as valid records(rows). As you go forward you can back your farther historical data up.

Comment: change the table so there is one date column and a status column.  Put the date of the status update in the date column and put the status info in the status column

Comment: This is a weird question. Tables can be altered in all DBMS I know about, of course they can. What makes you think the opposite? That's why the SQL languages has the `ALTER TABLE` statement.

Answer (score 3):

Possible: yes. A good solution: **probably not!**

You should consider [normalizing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your data:

```
table: records
 - ID (key)
 - name
 - description

table: record_history
 - record_ID (composite key part)
 - date (composite key part)
 - status
```